# SVN subversion.javahl.ClientException: General filesystem error

Tags: svn, git-svn

It is regarding SVN repository. I have made changes in the sparse checkout file, When I commit the changes in the SVN, I am seeing below issue. How to fix this?

1. Created workspace
2. Did Sparse checkout of code
3. svn commit -m "new project"

Seeing this issue intermittently

```
Transmitting file data .done
Committing transaction...
svn: E160000: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E160000: org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: General filesystem error
svn: current txn-sequence 174002 not expected 173502
:/svn/repos/local-test-project/db
```